# Trouble with stripping out everything from file before a found string

Tags: python

What I am trying to accomplish is search the file for a certain string when a match is found delete everything above it in the file and save the file. I am fairly new to Python so I am probably doing a few things wrong. Right now it creates a new file but nothing gets written into it.

Here is my code below:

```
file_type = ".php"
search_str = "}exit();}} ?><?php"
print("SANITIZING........")
print("FOLDERPATH being searched in: ", search_path)
print("FILETYPE being searched for : ", file_type)
print("STRING being searched       : ", search_str)

# LOOPING THROUGH ALL FOLDERS AND FILES
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(search_path):
    for file in files:

        # Apply file type filter   
        if file.endswith(file_type):
            bad_codes = ['exit();}} ?><?php']
            orig_file = open(os.path.join(subdir, file))

                for line in orig_file:
                    index = line.find(search_str)
                    if ( index != -1) :
                        new_file  = open(os.path.join(subdir, '-clean2-copy-' + file), 'w')
                        if not any(bad_code in line for bad_code in bad_codes):
                            new_file.write(line)
                        fw.write("CREATED SANITIZED COPY OF BAD PHP FILE: " + os.path.join(subdir, file) + " " + str(index) + "\r\n")
```

Comment: Are you trying to write the lines you deleted to the new file? Or the cleaned out good lines? Also your for loops seem different then your explanation of your goal. When you are looping through `bad_code in bad_codes`, you are looking through each individual character in `bad_codes` which doesn't seem like the intended effect either.

Comment: I would suggest trying to work through a smaller problem first and just print out the lines you find or use debugging with breakpoints to help you, as there are multiple parts of your code that seem to have errors in them.

Comment: I am trying to write the good lines to file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Over half of your posted code is overhead unrelated to the problem, such that it fails to exhibit the problem you claim.

Comment: Your code gives `NameError: name 'fw' is not defined`. Remove **all** above `bad_codes = `. Try with **one** file and give example data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply with a Boolean flag -- let's call it `found_str`.

```
found_str = False
for line in orig_file:
    if search_str in line:
        found_str = True
        continue

    if found_str:
        new_file.write(line)
```

If you prefer, make two loops: one to find the string, one to write the rest of the file:

```
for line in orig_file:
    if search_str in line:
        break

for line in orig_file:
    new_file.write(line)
```

Will either of these help you?